# Initializing double at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, floating-point, template-meta-programming

I'm writting a compile-time implementation of floating-point arithmetic through template metaprogramming. My implementation has the following characteristics:

- 16 bit signed integer exponent.
- 32 bit unsigned integer mantissa, **with no implicit most significant 1** (Thats done to simplify debugging).

The type is as follows:

```
template<bool S , std::int16_t E , std::uint32_t M>
struct number
{
    static constexpr const bool          sign     = S;
    static constexpr const std::int16_t  exponent = E;
    static constexpr const std::uint32_t mantissa = M;
};
```

The operations work well, but now I need a method to extract those values at compile-time and get the corresponding `double` values. Since the goal of compile-time arithmetic is to speed up computation injecting the solutions directly on the executable, I need a way to **effectively initialize a double constant at compile-time**.
So simple solutions involving `std::pow( 2.0 , E )` are not allowed.

As far I know double-precission IEE754 floats have a 10 bit signed exponent and a 53 bit wide unsigned integer mantissa. My attemped solution was to use type punning via an union:

```
template<bool S , std::int16_t E , std::uint32_t M>
struct to_runtime<tml::floating::number<S,E,M>>
{
    static constexpr const long unsigned int mantissa = M << (53 - 32);
    static constexpr const               int exponent = E + (53 - 32);


    struct double_parts 
    {
             unsigned int sign     : 1;
                      int exponent : 10;
        long unsigned int mantissa : 53;
    };

    union double_rep
    {
        double d;
        double_parts parts;
    };

    static constexpr const double_parts parts = { .sign = ((bool)S) ? 0 : 1 , .exponent = exponent , .mantissa = mantissa };
    static constexpr const double_rep   rep   = { .parts = parts };

    static constexpr double execute()
    {
        return rep.d;
    }
};
```

But this solution is not portable, invokes undefined behaviour (Since when doing type punning we read the member of the union which has not been written), and also I have some issues when realizing the conversion (This solution doesn't return the correct number).

**Is there any other way to initialize a `double` at compile-time given my data (sign, exponent, mantissa)?**

Comment: Just curious, why does this need to be done at compile time?

Comment: @NeilKirk Using `std::pow()` its easy, but doesn't serve to initialize  values at compile-time. Say, for example, we are computing a lookup-table: If we are able to compute that `double`s at compile-time, we can fill the array at compile time, something like `template<typename... FPs> constexpr const std::array<double,sizeof...(FPs)> compute_table() { return { to_runtime<FPs>... }; }`

Comment: @Manu343726 Why not have a program to calculate the lookup table instead of going through the trouble of re-implementing floating point math?

Comment: @BaummitAugen because the implementation is challenging ;), and (most important) no extra tools are required. Just C++.

Comment: Lookup tables are not always faster than performing the calculation. Sometimes it's faster for the CPU to just perform the calculation, than retrieve data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may implement a `constexpr` `pow2(std::int16_t)`, something like:

```
constexpr double pow2(std::int16_t e)
{
    return e == 0 ? 1. :
            e > 0 ? 2. * pow2(std::int16_t(e - 1)) :
                    0.5 * pow2(std::int16_t(e + 1));
}
```

or

```
constexpr double pow2(std::int16_t e)
{
    return e == 0 ? 1. :
                    ((e & 1) ? (e > 0 ? 2. : 0.5) : 1.)
                    * pow2(std::int16_t(e / 2))
                    * pow2(std::int16_t(e / 2));
}
```

And then

```
template<bool S , std::int16_t E , std::uint32_t M>
struct number
{
    static constexpr const double value = (sign ? -1. : 1.) * M * pow2(E);
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/YezU9z)

Comment: +1 Finally I have followed a similar solution, using bit shifting instead of recursion, since this is for powers of two. Indeed, that solution results in some overflows during shifting on big numbers. So I will mix up both solutions. Thanks anyway.